# Cypress - element is detached from the DOM error

Tags: javascript, dom, automation, cypress

I tested our (nearly all of the components are created by DevExtreme) web application but I have a strange re-rendering problem.

I posted a picture of the error message. As you can see the "element exists" and "element is visible" assertions both pass. The next action command `click`, `type`, `clear` sometimes gives me this error.

I watched the network but there are no suspicious API requests.

How can I fix it?

[image]

```
  cy.get("div.c-title.pe-2.me-2.active")
    .parent()
    .find("[name='Property Unsafe']")
    .parent()
    .find(".dx-item-content")
    .contains("Yes")
    .scrollIntoView()
    .should("be.visible")
    .should("be.exist")
    .click();
```

[image]
You can see which components are I working on it. (I get similar errors frequently from every components not just dropdown or text input)

Hello, the issue is still the same. Not working.
As you can see the latest updates here: I used `Cypress.dom.isAttached($el)` I re-queried until the element was attached into dom with Cypress recurse library. Still the result same.

```
  recurse(
    () =>
      cy.get(
        "#txtErrormeter_number > .dx-texteditor-container > .dx-texteditor-input-container > .dx-texteditor-input"
      ),
    ($el) => Cypress.dom.isAttached($el),
    {
      debugLog: true,
      log: true,
      limit: 50, // max number of iterations
      timeout: 10000, // time limit in ms
      delay: 250, // delay before next iteration, ms
    }
  ).then(() => {
    cy.get(
      "#txtErrormeter_number > .dx-texteditor-container > .dx-texteditor-input-container > .dx-texteditor-input"
    ).then(($el) => {
      if (Cypress.dom.isAttached($el)) {
        cy.log("aattacchheeed");
        cy.wrap($el)
          .clear({ force: true })
          .type(variables.meterId, { force: true });
      } else {
        cy.log("NOOOOOOTTTTTTTTTT aattacchheeed");
      }
    });
  });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Cypress log is saying you have a `.click()` two lines above the `scrollIntoView()`, but it is not in the posted test code.

You should split the long command after that first click, it is most likely causing the re-render.

Whatever you selected above click #1 should be selected again after it.

I can't tell what the context is, only a mention of DevExtreme. If you provide more information about the control (select, input, dropdown) it would be more useful.

Also the correct check for attachment is [isAttached()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/dom#Is-attached) not `visible` or `exist`.

```js
.then(($el) => {
  expect(Cypress.dom.isAttached($el).to.eq(true)
})
```

Comment: hello, I added more information. Yes codes are not the same but this code gives errors too, I just wanted to show the basic one.  Thank you so much for your help, I will try the isAttached() command, maybe it would solve my problem.